# .htaccess protected directory and curl

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

I want to disallow access to all files and folders in protected directory on my server.

I have used this in `.htaccess` file in that directory:

```
Deny from all
```

But the problem is I also want to use curl from another website to query one file in this directory:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$post_data = array();
$post_data['token'] = $token;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$url = 'https://my-website.com/protected-dir/file.php';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) { 
     return(curl_errno($curl)); 
} else{
    return $response;
}

curl_close($curl);
```

Now I get error 22 from CURL. I want to protect direct access to all files and folders in that directory. What are my options?

1. I can place this directory outside of web root, but how would I use CURL then? (what is the URL to that file?)
2. other solutions?

Comment: You either can or you can't access a file over HTTP. You can't have both. Currently you can't. What you probably want is some *password protection* for that directory…?

Answer (score 2):

The easy answer is to leave the file inside the document root and then just add an `allow` exception to the `.htaccess` file, which lists the IP address of the remote server you want to allow hits from:

```
allow from 1.2.3.4
deny from all
```

But note this will allow any user on that machine to grab the file. The secure answer is to always put sensitive content outside the document root and never rely on .htaccess to protect you. Then create an authenticated proxy page for any exceptions.

```
public/
    index.php
    secret.php
private/
    secret_file
```

Where `public` is the document root, `index.php` is your regular site, and `secret.php` would be something like:

```
// run some checks to ensure that you're allowed to do this:
//   maybe check source IP
//   maybe check for a username and password
//   maybe check for a specific bearer token in a header
header('Content-Type: whatever');
readfile('/path/to/private/secret_file');
```

Comment: Minor point... "leave the file inside the document root" - It would seem the file in question is in a `/protected-dir` subdirectory.

Comment: Yes but that subdirectory is in the document root. I.e., by "inside the document root" I mean, "_anywhere_ in the document root," and not necessarily at its top level. The point being that "completely outside the doc root" is stronger security than "protecting" a directory by dropping an .htaccess in it.

Comment: Preferably you configure a clearly named folder in your core server configuration to be protected in some way; that way you can use the very performant native web server functions instead of involving PHP, and it’s slightly less of a chance of screwing up the config than with an .htaccess file. Adding PHP to this, with which you may create your own bugs, just to avoid this misconfiguration chance is maybe a bit overkill.

Comment: I cant add exception because anybody can query that. And the process needs to be automated (no user login etc..), just a curl doing some checks. So I guess I need to learn how to use curl with password.

Comment: @Toniq "I cant add exception because anybody can query that." - But isn't the CURL request coming from _your_ server? Or can this CURL request originate from "any" server (so this file really needs to be "public")?

Comment: @MrWhite - curl is coming from wordpress plugin to my website, to verify license.

Comment: @Toniq A "WordPress plugin" that can presumably be installed on any website? In that case this particular file needs to be "public". You can embed "secrets" in the plugin code (query string on the request, unique User-Agent, etc.) but as soon as someone looks at the code (on their website), it's no longer "secret".

Comment: Yes, on any webite. I know that anybody can look at the code, thats not the point. I want to do the best possible for preventing those who do look at the code not to endanger my system on my website which is meant to control everything.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem (from comments) that this code is part of a WordPress plugin that can potentially be installed on any website. In which case this file needs to be "public".

The file shouldn't be in the protected directory to begin with. However, you can block everything *except* the file in question using a `<FilesMatch>` container and a regex/negative lookahead.

For example:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!file\.php$).*">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Everything is blocked except for requests to `file.php`. Note that the `Deny` directive is formerly deprecated and you should be using the corresponding `Require` directive instead on Apache 2.4+. (But note that you should not mix both old and new authentication directives.)

I assuming that your script contains the usual validation, for example:

- fails early on any non-POST request.
- fails on any POST request that does not contain a suitable `token` parameter.
- enforces a "delay" on any failed *token* requests to prevent brute force attacks.

You could also set a custom User-Agent string as part of the CURL (POST) request and check for this in your script or earlier in `.htaccess` - but that's just smoke and mirrors and doesn't really offer any additional "protection".

Comment: I do have this :  if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && realpath(__FILE__) == realpath( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {    
    header( 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden', TRUE, 403 );
    exit();
}                       How would this delay work?